# Making an Array from Database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have database connection. I want to make an array but something is problem i think. Here is my array code:

```
$var = "SELECT SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,1,4) AS year,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,6,2) AS month,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,9,2) AS day,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,12,2) AS saat,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,15,2) AS dakika,Guc FROM Urun WHERE Date(KayitTarihi)=\"".$link_m."\"";

$result = $mysqli->query($var);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {$data[] = $row;}

print_r($data);

$no=1;$total_deger=count($data);
echo $total_deger;

for($i=0;$i<$total_deger);$i++){
    $xxx[i]="[Date.UTC(".$data[i]['year'].",".$data[i]['month'].",".$data[i]['day'].",".$data[i]['saat'].",".$data[i]['dakika'].",00),".$data[i]['Guc']."]";if($no < $total_deger){echo ",";}
    echo $xxx[i];
}
```

When I run this code, nothing happens in page. When I write to for example 0 for i. I can see my array value. Where do I mistake?

Comment: Syntax error:-  `for($i=0;$i<$total_deger);$i++){`  check the extra bracket? Is it a TYPO?

Comment: yes, It's ok now.. Thank you. But now my $no=1 and I have if statement $no<$total_deger. $total_deger is 23. But it looks like $no<$total_deger and my if statement is true. What is wrong?

Comment: Also `echo $xxx[i];` should be `echo $xxx[$i];` **Look at your PHP Error log when things dont work as expected**

Comment: That also applies to this line ALL the `i` variables need to be `$i` in `$xxx[i]="[Date.UTC(".$data[i]['year'].",".$data[i]['month'].",".$data[i]['day'].",".$data[i]['saat'].",".$data[i]['dakika'].",00),".$data[i]['Guc']."]";if($no < $total_deger){echo ",";}`

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything. **and debug your own code**

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was C# person and now learning PHP. So I forget $ sign.Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code with correction and suggestion (both are commented):-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);// display those errors
$var = "SELECT SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,1,4) AS year,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,6,2) AS month,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,9,2) AS day,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,12,2) AS saat,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,15,2) AS dakika,Guc FROM Urun WHERE Date(KayitTarihi)=\"".$link_m."\"";

$result = $mysqli->query($var);

$data = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // check you got results or not
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $data[] = $row; // assign them
    }
}

//foreach ($result as $row) {$data[] = $row;} // not needed 

print_r($data);

$no=1;

$total_deger= count($data);

echo $total_deger;

for($i=0;$i<$total_deger;$i++){ // remove )

$xxx[$i]="[Date.UTC(".$data[$i]['year'].",".$data[$i]['month'].",".$data[$i]['day'].",".$data[$i]['saat'].",".$data[$i]['dakika'].",00),".$data[$i]['Guc']."]"; // use $i  instead of i
if($no < $total_deger)
{
    echo ",";
}
echo $xxx[$i];

}
```

Note:- Always add some error reporting code. So that all errors will populated and you can rectify those

***Also better would be to use `foreach()` instead of `for` loop (as it will take care of indexes itself):-***

```
//use foreach
foreach ($data as $dat){
    echo "[Date.UTC(".$data['year'].",".$data['month'].",".$data['day'].",".$data['saat'].",".$data['dakika'].",00),".$data['Guc']."]";
}
```

Comment: i have added a `foreach()` suggestion,which is more good for you.

Comment: When I use foreach again just seeing ,,,,, not my value.

Comment: my total_deger=9 but my output is 
[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),],[Date.UTC(,,,,,00),]

Comment: use either one (either foreach or for loop, not both)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you want to check your SQL query returns rows. Then I think you need to modify your `foreach` to a `while` as below. Also checking that rows are returned before looping.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

As per example given here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp